# Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server ( React Native )

Tags: android, react-native, npx

when i open 2 terminal

1. `npx react-native start`
2. `npx react-native run-android`

actually there are no error while running run-android,
but at the first window, metro bundler doesn't work

1. I try to delete the application from device / emulator, doesn't work at all
2. I try delete .gradle folder and run ./gradlew clean, and try to run again but still show the same issue

Comment: when you run npx react-native start, what do you get as output in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this issue by removing this line:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

From `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`